# InvalidUrl Bulk API creating a bulk job using postman

Tags: apex, rest-api, bulk-api

URI i'm using is: https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/async/46.0/job so in my case example is https://cs89.salesforce.com/services/async/46.0/job but it still says InvalidUrl.

X-Session-Id i put there the Access token

[image: X-Session-Id i put there the Access token]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is payload of request message?

Comment: {
  "jobInfo" : {
   "operation" : "query",
   "object" : "Account",
   "contentType" : "JSON",
   "concurrencyMode" : "Parallel"
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with your payload - getting details of a job (what you're attempting with operation *query*) should go against `/async/<api_version>/job/jobId`. It should have an empty request body. The `/job` resource is for creating jobs (operation: *insert*)

Comment: can you elaborate on your answer, I tired what was said and I still get an answer?
url: https://test.salesforce.com/services/async/48.0/job
headers 
Content-Type: application/json
X-SFDC-Session: <fresh token>
{
 "jobInfo": {
  "operation": "insert",
  "object": "Account",
  "contentType": "JSON",
  "concurrencyMode": "Parallel"
 }
}

I still get the error: 
{
    "exceptionCode": "InvalidJob",
    "exceptionMessage": "Unable to parse Job"
}

Comment: @user1019042 Please ask by clicking the [Ask Question](//salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.