# Salesforce Postman create job post in xml but not in json

Tags: apex, rest-api, bulk-api

I'm following this example to create a job using json:
[InvalidUrl Bulk API creating a bulk job using postman](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/267736/invalidurl-bulk-api-creating-a-bulk-job-using-postman)

I've been successful to use the request body as xml instead of json, but I desire it to be in json. Here is what I tried to mimic in the example

```
POST url: test.salesforce.com/services/async/48.0/job
```

headers:

- Content-Type: application/json
- X-SFDC-Session: 'fresh token'

Body

```
{ 
    "jobInfo": { 
        "operation": "insert",
        "object": "Account",
        "contentType": "JSON",
        "concurrencyMode": "Parallel"
    }
}
```

I still get this error:

```
{ "exceptionCode": "InvalidJob", "exceptionMessage": "Unable to parse Job" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON request body doesn't use a top-level `jobInfo` key. Rather than converting XML-based code, reference the JSON examples in the [Bulk API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_jobs_create.htm):

> Example JSON request body

```
{
  "operation" : "insert",
  "object" : "Account",
  "contentType" : "CSV"
}
```